# Do questions about the benefits of a plant or herbs fit in this SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just as the title says, do any questions regarding the benefits of certain plants or herbs fit in this SE? It seems that this is all about gardening. Should I propose one?

Comment: Define "benefits", please.

Comment: Like benefits if I drink it, or if I make a tea out of it.

Comment: Hi Cary! [This section](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the [help] lists what we can and can't ask here. It specifically says that these types of questions are off topic. I'm not a moderator or decision maker though, so I'm just leaving this as a comment. You might have a question that would work.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Yes, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Sue you should turn that into an answer :). Also don't be hesitant to answer on meta, policies are developed here on meta, by the users, not the mods.

Comment: @waxeagle Thanks for the encouragement and clarification. I'll write an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This section](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of our [help center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help) lists what types of questions are on topic here. Unfortunately, it clearly states that questions about

> the health and nutritional aspects of fruits/vegetables

are not allowed.

That said, if you've chosen something to grow for those purposes, please feel free to ask the same types of growth and care questions as you would for any other plant.

I've done some research and the closest thing I can find is [Health SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/). They have nutrition and tea tags, and there may be something there that would help you. I'd suggest having a look at those, or asking in their meta.